# Wordpress filter "wp_get_nav_menu_items" filter shows only last child

Tags: wordpress, menu

I'm trying to add latest posts to my footer menu, so I used `wp_get_nav_menu_items` filter.
I'm going to skip the filter itself, just in the end of the function I get an array(2) of posts. I've added all the additional data to them (like menu_parent_id etc.). The problem is final menu contains only the last post. Even if I set `$items[0] = $items[1];` so that both items are identical. It does not depend on a particular menu or post amount - always the last item only. I'll leave the code in quickly-reproducible format: just a filter and JSON-encoded items:

```
add_filter('wp_get_nav_menu_items', function ($items, $menu, $args) {

return json_decode('[{
        "ID": 2576,
        "post_author": "3",
        "post_date": "2020-05-11 23:46:15",
        "post_date_gmt": "2020-05-11 23:46:15",
        "post_content": "",
        "post_title": "Testr",
        "post_excerpt": "",
        "post_status": "publish",
        "comment_status": "open",
        "ping_status": "open",
        "post_password": "",
        "post_name": "testr",
        "to_ping": "",
        "pinged": "",
        "post_modified": "2020-05-11 23:46:15",
        "post_modified_gmt": "2020-05-11 23:46:15",
        "post_content_filtered": "",
        "post_parent": 0,
        "guid": "http:\/\/mysite.local\/?p=2576",
        "menu_order": 0,
        "post_type": "post",
        "post_mime_type": "",
        "comment_count": "0",
        "filter": "raw",
        "db_id": 2576,
        "object_id": "",
        "menu_item_parent": "0",
        "url": "http:\/\/mysite.local\/?p=2576",
        "title": "Testr",
        "target": "",
        "classes": [],
        "type": "",
        "object": "",
        "attr_title": "",
        "description": "",
        "xfn": "",
        "status": ""
    }, {
        "ID": 3439,
        "post_author": "3",
        "post_date": "2020-05-11 23:28:49",
        "post_date_gmt": "2020-05-11 23:28:49",
        "post_content": "",
        "post_title": "Test",
        "post_excerpt": "",
        "post_status": "publish",
        "comment_status": "open",
        "ping_status": "open",
        "post_password": "",
        "post_name": "test-2",
        "to_ping": "",
        "pinged": "",
        "post_modified": "2020-05-11 23:28:49",
        "post_modified_gmt": "2020-05-11 23:28:49",
        "post_content_filtered": "",
        "post_parent": 0,
        "guid": "http:\/\/mysite.local\/?p=3439",
        "menu_order": 0,
        "post_type": "post",
        "post_mime_type": "",
        "comment_count": "0",
        "filter": "raw",
        "db_id": 3439,
        "object_id": "",
        "menu_item_parent": "0",
        "url": "http:\/\/mysite.local\/?p=3439",
        "title": "Test",
        "target": "",
        "classes": [],
        "type": "",
        "object": "",
        "attr_title": "",
        "description": "",
        "xfn": "",
        "status": ""
    }]');
});
```

Did anyone have this issue before, please help, it drives me nuts :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was the problem. Each menu item must contain a `menu_order` property, or else wordpress sorting function will overwrite the same value over and over again showing only the last post.